# Issue with rendering WriteableBitmap from Image in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, scale, writeablebitmap, scaletransform

I have a next problem, I need to convert array of bytes to `WriteableBitmap` with resize. I write next code.

```
private byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] array, double maxWidth, double maxHeight)
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = null;

    var stream = new MemoryStream(array);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0);
    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    stream.Close();
    var img = new Image();
    img.Source = bmp;
    double scaleX = 1;
    double scaleY = 1;
    if (bmp.PixelHeight > maxHeight)
    {
        scaleY = maxHeight / bmp.PixelHeight;
    }
    if (bmp.PixelWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        scaleX = maxWidth / bmp.PixelWidth;
    }
    wb = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0);
    var scale = Math.Min(scaleY, scaleX);
    wb.Render(img, new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = scale, ScaleY = scale });
    wb.Invalidate();
    return Utils.Encode(wb);

}
```

After call `wb.Render(img, new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = scale, ScaleY = scale });`, `wb` has zero pixels.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

```
private byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] array, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(array);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    stream.Close();
    var img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage();

    double scaleX = 1;
    double scaleY = 1;
    if (bmp.PixelHeight > maxHeight)
    {
        scaleY = maxHeight / bmp.PixelHeight;
    }
    if (bmp.PixelWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        scaleX = maxWidth / bmp.PixelWidth;
    }

    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    var scale = Math.Min(scaleY, scaleX);
    wb.Render(img, new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = scale, ScaleY = scale });
    wb.Invalidate();

    return Utils.Encode(wb);
}
```

Comment: as I say it's not help all pixels has 0 value see image dl.dropbox.com/u/16517591/screen.png

Comment: That's not the only thing I changed. Try the code. I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I try it, situation is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0);
```

To:

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);
```